# How to customize a method like 'stringWithFormat'?

Tags: objective-c, format, cstring, stringwithformat

I want to customize a method with formated string input and (const char *) return,but the problem is like below... Can anyone tell me how to resolve it? Thanks.
[image: I want to customize a method with formated string input and (const char *) return,but the problem is like below... Can anyone tell me how to resolve it? Thanks.]

Comment: Do you want to pass variable number of arguments?

Comment: Yes. I want to customize a method like [NSString stringWithFormat:<#(NSString *), ...#>];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-(const char *)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *lString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    [lString autorelease];
    va_end(args);
    return [lString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Comment: @stream: Amazing you accepted but din't upvoted!!! Always upvote if you like an answer. this boosts the person who gives time for answer. And by reading you learn something. :)